# Defining probabilities in a roullete wheel in Java

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to implement a roullete wheel in java.

I create two methods. One is to create the roullete wheel and another to rotate the roullete wheel.

How I should do to implement the probalibities. My methods are not doing that.
My method to create the roullete wheel is totally wrong.

For example if I get:

50% for chromosome with fitness 86

35% for chromosome with fitness 88

15% for chromosome with fitness 90

How I can make sure that those 15% will have more chance to be selected?

```
    public void createRolette(Population population) throws Exception {

    int swap;

       for (int i=0; i<populationSize; i++){
           population.getIndividual(i);
           Simulator.allocateTask(i);
           rouletteId.add(i); 
           rouletteFit.add(calcFitness(i)); 
       }   


       for (int i = 0; i < rouletteFit.size() - 1; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < rouletteFit.size() - i - 1; j++) {
                if (rouletteFit.get(j) > rouletteFit.get(j+1))
                {
                    swap = rouletteFit.get(j);
                    rouletteFit.set(j, rouletteFit.get(j+1));
                    rouletteFit.set(j+1, swap);

                    swap = rouletteId.get(j);
                    rouletteId.set(j, rouletteId.get(j+1));
                    rouletteId.set(j+1, swap);
                }
          }
        }    
        System.out.println(rouletteId.toString());
        System.out.println(rouletteFit.toString());

        }



        public int rotateRolette(Population population) {           
               Integer SelectedIndv = (int)(Math.random()* (rouletteId.size())); // faz a escolha entre 0 e o numero maximo de elementos; 
               return rouletteId.get(SelectedIndv);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your code does. But for roulette wheel you should do somethin like this:

- create an array to put all fitness values in
- calculate the fitness of all individuals and save it in the array
- calculate the sum of all fitness values and divide each fitness by that sum (normalize)
- create an array with the cumulative sum. For Instance: For fitness values [0.1,0.2,0.3.0.4] your array shuld be [0.1,0.3,0.6,1.0]
- draw a number [0,1]
- loop throuhgh your array with the cumulative sum values and find the first value that is bigger than your random value. The ID is the id of your individual. For instance: If you draw 0.05, your ID would be 0 (the first individual). If you draw 0.8 your ID should be 3 (the last individual)

Answer (score 0):

An possible implementation (using Java 8) of the steps described in the previous answer:

```
class RouletteWheelSelector {

public Population<DoubleGene, Double>
select(Population<DoubleGene, Double> population, int count) {
    // The incremental fitness probability array.
    final double[] incremental = incremental(probabilities(population));
    final Random random = new Random();

    return IntStream.range(0, count)
        // Select the individual index.
        .map(i -> indexOf(incremental, random.nextDouble()))
        // Select the individual.
        .mapToObj(i -> population.get(i))
        // Create the new population object.
        .collect(Population.toPopulation());
}

// Calculate the fitness probabilities of the given population.
static double[] probabilities(Population<?, Double> population) {
    final double[] fitness = population.stream()
        .mapToDouble(pt -> pt.getFitness())
        .toArray();
    final double sum = Arrays.stream(fitness).sum();

    return Arrays.stream(fitness)
        .map(v -> v/sum)
        .toArray();
}

// Create the incremental probability array.
static double[] incremental(final double[] values) {
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; ++i) {
        values[i] += values[i - 1];
    }
    return values;
}

// Binary search for the individual index for a given probability.
static int indexOf(final double[] incr, final double v) {
    int imin = 0;
    int imax = incr.length;
    int index = -1;

    while (imax > imin && index == -1) {
        final int imid = (imin + imax) >>> 1;

        if (imid == 0 || (incr[imid] >= v && incr[imid - 1] < v)) {
            index = imid;
        } else if (incr[imid] <= v) {
            imin = imid + 1;
        } else if (incr[imid] > v) {
            imax = imid;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
}
```

The code has been extracted from the 'RouletteWheelSelector' of the [Jenetics](http://jenetics.io) project.